# How to integrate File System to visual studio Team Explorer using TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, tfs, filesystems

I'm having **TFS2012** as my versions control system. As so (old version)- it can't integrate with **visual code**. 
As a bypass - I'm using the **Visual Studio 2017** Team Expolorer to control my pending changes. 
(I'm having a separate workspace for my client code).
The problem is that even after editing a file in the **visual code**, which is changed in the **file system**, I can't see the file as pending in the **Pending changes** list. I need to go and check it out manually.
What should I do in order to have to edited files (in VS code => File System) to be automatically checked out in the visual studio Team Explorer ? Should I use a special add-on ?

Comment: What's "visual code"? Do you mean [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)? Do you use Local workspace or Server workspace? Are you able to see the pending changes if you edit in Team Explorer? Please check the `Excluded Changes` under `Pending Changes` to see whether the changes there.

Comment: @Cece dong - thanks for your reply. Yes - By saying "visual code", I meant to Visual Studio Code. I'm using a Server workspace (Location: server) - I'm not fully aware of the meanings of "server" or "Local". I can see the files as "pending" if I edit them in Team Explorer (but not when doing so in the visual studio code) - the changed files are not under "exclude" - they are not under pending at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you are using Local workspace, and check whether the changes in **Excluded Changes** under **Pending Changes**.

If you are working in a [local workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops), Visual Studio can detect changes that you make outside the system. If you edit a file outside Visual Studio (for example, in Notepad) the change automatically appears in your **Included Changes**.

If you add or remove a file outside Visual Studio, for example, in Windows Explorer (File Explorer in Windows 8), the **Detected changes** link appears in the **Excluded Changes** section. Choose this link if you want to include these changes. The **Promote Candidate Changes** dialog box appears.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/develop-code-manage-pending-changes?view=azure-devops#work-with-automatically-detected-changes

Comment: Thanks again - I'll try this - can you tell me in a nut shell what is the meaning\differences between local and server ?

Comment: Check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops